# Bluemix scalable container group custom domain SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, docker, ibm-cloud

Ok, I have finally managed to get my node.js container up and running using a scalable container group and a custom domain.

The problem that now remains is: How do you get the self-signed certificate to be used by Bluemix when accessing the app through https://my-app.mydomain.com?

Https works, but it shows the wildcard *.mybluemix.net certificate instead of the one I added to the domain that I added to my organisation. Visiting https://my-app.mybluemix.net is ok since then the wildcard mybluemix.net certificate is valid.

Yes, I have seen this one as well as read the SSL part of the Bluemix docs.

[developerWorks: SSL Certificates and Bluemix Custom Domains](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/09/28/ssl-certificates-bluemix-custom-domains/)

Comment: This was in the doc you referenced, but can you confirm that you've configured your DNS to use an A record pointing to 75.126.81.68?  If you're using 75.126.81.66, then you would see the behavior you mentioned.

Comment: No, I created a CNAME record towards my-app.mybluemix.net. I guess I missunderstod that part, will create a A-record instead.

Comment: The comment by @jimmc is the correct answer to this question. Creating an A-record pointing to 75.126.81.68 worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: good to hear.  I've converted the comment to an answer and included your info about using a CNAME record so that others may benefit.

Comment: For future reference, the Securing Apps topic in the Bluemix documentation provides information about SSL certificates: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/securingapps.html

Comment: Yes, I read that one even if it talks about apps, not containers. As it turns out that part is applicable also to containers. It does not explicitly state that you need to setup an A-record, however it does it implicitly since A-records point towards IP-addresses, but I guess I am not the only one with only vague knowledge of DNS and the difference between A-records and CNAME ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DNS should use an A record pointing to `75.126.81.68`.  This IP address is used by Bluemix for SSL traffic in the US-South region.

If you are using an A record with `75.126.81.66` or use a CNAME record pointing to your app's route (e.g. my-app.mybluemix.net), then you will see the *.mybluemix.net certificate instead of your custom certificate that you uploaded to Bluemix and associated to your custom domain.